# Undefined Behavior : I have a situation here with postfix and prefix operator

Tags: php

I have a situation here with post fix and prefix operator.Take a look at below code snippet. I know some operator precedence exist. but i need a clear explanation regarding this.

```
<?php
    $a=0;
    echo $a++ + ++$a; //this will result 2 that is ok

    $b=0;
    echo $b++ - ++$b; //this should result 0 isn't it? but am getting -2!
 ?>
```

**Update** : The accepted answer describes **undefined behavior**

Comment: ... what makes you confused? Following the logic on your first equation, you should actually gets -2 no?

Comment: @Arun: That always happens if you make use of *undefined behaviour*. And what you do is undefined behaviour. So don't try to get an explanation that follows a deterministic logic as undefined is the opposite of that.

Comment: @hakre echo $c=($b++) - (++$b);
the result of this statement also getting -2. What you meant by undefined behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That always happens if you make use of *undefined behaviour*. And what you do is undefined behaviour. So don't try to get an explanation that follows a deterministic logic as undefined is the opposite of that.

The [PHP manual states](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

> ```
> // mixing ++ and + produces undefined behavior
> $a = 1;
> echo ++$a + $a++; // may print 4 or 5
> ```

You extended your question in a comment:

> `echo $c=($b++) - (++$b);` the result of this statement also getting -2. What you meant by undefined behavior?

```
$b = 0 and it shall:

$c=($b++) - (++$b);   | $b is 0  - process first brackets
$c= 0 - (++$b);       | $b is 1  - process second bracktes inner operator
$c= 0 - ($b);         | $b is 2  - process second brackets 
$c= 0 - 2;            | calculate
$c= -2;
```

This is obviously how it results *for your code when you execute it*. It is not defined that this will be always calculated that way, hence undefined. For example if the second bracket is processed first, you'll get a different result.

Comment: echo $c=($b++) - (++$b);
is this also under undefined behavior?

Comment: @Arun: Yes, it is. Imagine the second bracket is executed first.

Comment: @ARun: You're not the only one: [Why is $a + ++$a == 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709818/why-is-a-a-2/9709851)

Answer (score 2):

Due to [Incrementing/Decrementing Operators (PHP doc)](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

```
<?php
    $a=0;
    echo $a++ + ++$a; // 0 + 2 = 2

    $b=0;
    echo $b++ - ++$b; // 0 - 2 = -2
 ?>
```

`$a++` returns `0` and increments `$a` by 1 (`$a == 1`);
`++$a` increments `$a` by 1 (`$a == 2`) and returns `2`

Answer (score 2):

The results are perfectly fine:

$a++ prints the value and increments it immediatly
++$a increments before output

so in the first case this would be like:

1. $a=0
2. output 0
3. increment $a by 1: $a=1
4. increment again (before output): $a=2
5. output 2

0+2 = 2

in the second case:

1. $b=0
2. output 0
3. increment $b by 1: $b=1
4. increment again (before output): $b=2
5. output 2

0 - 2 = -2

It justz does what it says.

Regards,

STEFAN