# What should be the output of echo ++$a + $a++

Tags: php, operator-precedence, post-increment, pre-increment

In the PHP manual, [operator precedence section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), there is this example:

```
// mixing ++ and + produces undefined behavior
$a = 1;
echo ++$a + $a++; // may print 4 or 5
```

I understand the behavior is undefined because of the following reason:

Since `x + y = y + x` the interpreter is free to evaluate `x` and `y` for addition in any order in order to optimize speed and/or memory. I concluded this after looking at the [C code example in this article](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP10-C.+Do+not+depend+on+the+order+of+evaluation+of+subexpressions+or+the+order+in+which+side+effects+take+place).

My question is that the output of the above mentioned PHP code should be `4` no matter which way the expression and sub-expressions are evaluated:

- op1 = ++$a => $a = 2, op1 = 2; op2 = $a++ => op2 = 2, $a = 3; 2 + 2 = 4
- op1 = $a++ => op1 = 1, $a = 2; op2 = ++$a => op2 = 3, $a = 3; 1 + 3 = 4

Where does the 5 come from? Or should I learn more about how the operators work?

Edit:

I have been staring at [Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) section but still could not figure out why 5.

> ++$a: Pre-increment -- Increments $a by one, ***then*** returns $a.
>   $a++: Post-increment -- Returns $a, ***then*** increments $a by one.

Comment: Did you really get 5 printed while running this code?

Comment: No. I always got 4 with a few versions of PHP. It is the word _may_, it means I could run this code a million times getting the reesult 4 but there is no _guarantee_.

Comment: @H2CO3: I am more interested in knowing _why 5_.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9709818/1607098

Comment: Bear in mind that a compiler/interpreter may well choose to do someting in a different way depending on circumstances - are there registers available, can we do something clever because of how it's used next [e.g. staying with the value calculated in a register]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C. Removing that tag.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = 1;
++ (preincrement) gives a = 2 (higher precedence than +, and LR higher precedence than postincrement)
++ (postincrement) gives a = 3 (higher precedence than +)
+ (add) gives 2 + 3 = 5
```

$a is initially set to 1. The ++$a then preincrements $a before using it in the formula, setting it to 2, and pushing that value onto the lexer stack. The $++ is then executed, because incrementor has a higher precedence than +, and that value is also pushed that result onto the lexer stack; and the addition that then takes place adds the lexer stack's 2 result to the lexer stack's 3 result giving a result of 5, which is then echoed. The value of $a once the line has executed is 3.

**OR**

```
a = 1;
++ (preincrement) gives a = 2 (higher precedence than +, and LR higher precedence than postincrement)
+ (add) gives 2 + 2 = 4 (the value that is echoed)
++ (postincrement) gives a = 3 (incremented __after__ the variable is echoed)
```

$a is initially set to 1. When the formula is parses, the ++$a preincrements $a, setting it to 2 before using it in the formula (pushing the result to the lexer stack). The result from the lexer stack and the current value of $a are then added together giving 4; and this value is echoed. Finally, $a is postincremented, leaving a value of 3 in $a.

Comment: I've edited my question. I had thought of this too but later realized that post increment will return the current value (i.e. 2), _then_ increment a.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will give you 5 because the **right side operator works first by its priority/precendence** and after that the sum(+) operator will work.
So first increment makes it to 2 and second makes it to 3 and after that both will sum  and outputs you the result as 5

```
$result = ++$a + $a++;
```

`++$a` outputs as 2

`$a++` outputs as 2 3 only but internally it wll be incremented.

finally sum will happens as 2+3 = 5

Comment: "Yes it will give you 5" - rather "Yes it may also give you 5".

Comment: Even if $a is 3 after $a++ is evaluated, the expression $a++ still evaluates to 2, so the sum is 2+2.

Answer (score 0):

Mark, I believe you are wrong!

Post-increment: Returns $a, then increments $a by one. (from documentation)

So there is no way to get $a value of 3 in sum operation.

Comment: The point is that the result is unpredictable: OP was asking how it was possible to get a result of 5, not whether it did give a result of 5

Comment: But then an explanation: "++$a gives 0 and $a++ gives 5, so 0 + 5 = 5" would give same effort. I mean, both are against documentation.